# Is there a polynomial time algorithm for Poly-trees (oriented trees) isomorphism?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, computational-complexity, trees, graph-isomorphism

In terms of graph isomorphism complexity classes Trees have a polynomial time algorithm and Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG's) do not (so far).

What about Poly-trees (oriented trees)? These are DAG's where the possible paths from a node are all trees. Unlike trees, Poly-tree nodes can have several parents.

Are polytrees in the isomorphism complexity class of DAG's or Trees, so far?